# Serilizing internal fields of a class with gson in SRetrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I use Retrofit from Square as my REST Client for communications in Android. I discovered that some of server side services do not serialize well our objects. How to serilize only internal fields of an object?

Like in this example, how to convert this class:

```
public class Car {
    private String plate;
    private String carName;
}
```

Into this JSON representation (ignore cases):

```
{
    "plate":"abc123",
    "carname":"BMW"
}
```

**NOT** into this:

```
{
    "car": 
    {
        "plate":"abc123",
        "carname":"BMW"
     }
}
```

I actually have to do this kind of serialization for some classes and standard serialization for others.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the request using retrofit, send each part of the Car object as an **@Query** (for **@GET** requests) and as an **@Field** (for **@POST** requests.)

**Example request**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("www.foo.bar/example.json")
ExampleResponse getExample(@Field("plate") Car.plate, 
    @Field("carname") Car.carname);
```

**Using @Body**

```
@POST("www.foo.bar/example.json")
    ExampleResponse getExample(@Body Car car);
```

(using **@POST** with **@Body** does not require **@FormUrlEncoded**)

Comment: You will only need the **@FormUrlEncoded** for **@POST** requests

Comment: That's very unhandy way of doing serialization. Is there no other way?

Comment: I hadn't worked with @Body, but was able to take a look at this method. I'll add another answer, as this would work for serialization for others.

Comment: I think it's wrong answer. It does not convert it to JSON representation. It actually make it something like: plate=someplate&carname=somecarname